# Naive bayes features to classify digits

Tags: python, machine-learning, naivebayes

So, I would like to classify numbers, represented by a 2D array, with naive bayes.
The current set of features I use exists solely out of whether a pixel is black or not (on or off). With this feature I get 78% correct on average, and I would like to up this percentage to somewhere in the 80-85% range by adding in more complex features.

So far, I have tried adding the width and height of the number, the amount of black pixels per half and per quarter to it, yet it seems to do nothing, and the ratings stay exactly the same as without them.

What else could I do with this array to create useful features out of ?

EDIT:
forgot to mention, the image is binary.

Comment: is your image binary? or greyscale?

Comment: Stupid of me not to mention, it is binary

Comment: think about Bagging+Boosting. Meaning: I am assuming you are treating each class as a label...what you should do is try and convert this to a two class problem (is it 1 or not, is it 2 or not and so on), then you can treat them as weak classifiers and use some kind of polling to identify classes.

Comment: You are using all the features (pixel map), using features derived/abstracted from this would not gain you monumental improvements. That said try running PCA to reduce noise and most discriminant ED..but I digress here...

Comment: fahad daniyal why would using features derived from the pixel map not gain me any performance ? Currently I only use whether a pixel is on or not, but I dont use its location or the concentration of certain pixels yet. I was sort of thrown off because what I tried hadn't worked yet. I am convinced though that using the location of certain pixels still can get me some gain.

Comment: are all your features equally weighted ?

Comment: so if you have a NxM image, you have got that many pixels, then you add 4 more numbers to it, do you imagine getting much separability, think about the maths behind NB

Comment: it depends on what dataset you trained for naive bayes so increasing percentage of naive bayes' correct predictions depends on its data because of frequenciencies of dataset. It seems you need a little modification for creating dataset according to your classes of images. you may share tangible dataset entities in your question.

Comment: fahad daniyal I managed to get the correct rating up to 80% now by using the position of pixels which are "on". I am just looking for more ways of improving this rating by adding more complex features. İlker Korkut I think the training is fine, since if it wasn't, then I dont think I wouldve reached the 78% and 80% ratings. I am looking for more complex features to add though, to improve this rating.

Comment: understand, then it seems you need an another algorithm before naive bayes' calculation, like `levenshtein distance` to converge your AxB matrix(2d array?) of your image's specs on trained dataset, may be another useful algorithm on image processing, so you can assume current data like trained data so classification may be more accurate.